# Access u-boot env variables set by fw_setenv from boot.scr

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I'm experimenting with nanopi board with ubuntu OS and u-boot bootloader.
When booted into system, I set u-boot environment variable with `fw_setenv`:

```
$ fw_setenv foo bar
```

On the following reboot I'd like to access this `foo` variable from the `/boot/boot.scr` script:

```
if [ -z "${foo}" ]; then
    echo "Fail"
else
    echo "Ok"
fi
```

I get `Fail`, so `foo` is inaccessible.
I've no experience with u-boot but I read that it has two sets of environment variables: one read-only (fixed as a part of U-boot image), and another read/write (user environment). So it looks like user environment is not accessible from `boot.scr` script? Is it true? How can I make my `foo` variable visible at the moment when boot.scr is executed?

Upd: My `/etc/fw_env.config` file:

```
# Block device
/dev/mmcblk1    0xc0000    0x20000
```

U-boot version: 2020.01

Comment: The U-Boot shell is not bash. The U-Boot hush shell is described here: https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CommandLineParsing

Comment: @Xypron True, but if-else constructions are still valid in Hush shell, aren't they? From your link: `similar to Bourne shell, with control structures like if...then...else...fi`

Comment: `[` command is often not built-in in embedded environments. Are you sure in the `hush` you have such command available?

Comment: @0andriy Yes, I've checked, it is available. I also checked other syntax (`if test ...`) with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is found. U-boot constants `CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_DEV`, `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET`, and `CONFIG_ENV_SIZE` did not match those in `/etc/fw_env.config`.
Solved the problem by changing these constants to

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_DEV          1
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET               0x3f8000
#define CONFIG_ENV_SIZE                 0x20000
```

recompiling u-boot and updating fw_env.config accordingly:

```
/dev/mmcblk1    0x3f8000    0x20000
```